# Open .desktop file from terminal

Tags: command-line, gtk, .desktop

I have this application Tmolex19 which can be opened from the start menu, but I can not open it from the terminal. Even if I use the following commands,

1. gio open TmoleX19.desktop
2. gtk-launch TmoleX19.desktop
3. xdg-open TmoleX19.desktop
4. gvfs-open TmoleX19.desktop

Every time it opens the gedit with the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=TmoleX19
Exec="/home/mslab/COSMOlogic/TmoleX19/TmoleX/TmoleX19"
Icon=/home/mslab/COSMOlogic/TmoleX19/.install4j/TmoleX19.png
Categories=Application;
```

Why do I need to open the program in this way?

This program has some visualization problems which can be solved. And I quote from the developer's reply

**try to set

export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=2.1

in your shell and then start TmoleX from there. The 3D viewer/builder uses OpenGL and in cases the graphics card drivers do not report to be able to provide certain OpenGL versions, the settings above should solve that problem.**

Any help is greatly appreciated.
I am using Linux Mint with

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-104-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
           Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa 
           base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, only Ubuntu and [official flavours of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. Linux Mint is not an official flavour of Ubuntu, so your question is off-topic here. Questions about Linux Mint can be asked on [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

That is the desktop shortcut you are trying to launch execute the binary file instead

```
sh /home/mslab/COSMOlogic/TmoleX19/TmoleX/TmoleX19
```

Comment: The program opens this way, thanks.

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay if you are still facing the GL issues please add the errors you are getting and I am sure someone will be able to help you here no need to bother with the vendor

Comment: Well actually, this software comes from the Turbomole suite, it is a visualizer. It is a .run file and installs automatically. It can be downloaded from https://www.3ds.com/products-services/biovia/products/molecular-modeling-simulation/solvation-chemistry/turbomoler/ .However, When I try to visualize a molecule is shows Java exception has occurred and the program crashes. This is what is bothering me.

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay have you setup your Java environment ? By default, Ubuntu does not come with Java (or the Java Runtime Environment, JRE) installed.  you can check with java -version command in your terminal if it is not installed you can install it with sudo apt install default-jre   and  sudo apt install default-jdk   more info can be found here  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-jre#1-overview

Comment: openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Literal answer to your question: in the terminal, just enter the command given on the `Exec` line of your .desktop file, ie.

```
/home/mslab/COSMOlogic/TmoleX19/TmoleX/TmoleX19
```

Possibly better solution for your problem: add the necessary environment variables to the .desktop file by changing the line

```
Exec="/home/mslab/COSMOlogic/TmoleX19/TmoleX/TmoleX19"
```

to

```
Exec=env LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=2.1 "/home/mslab/COSMOlogic/TmoleX19/TmoleX/TmoleX19"
```

and then start the program from the start menu as before.

Comment: The program opens this way, thanks. However, the problem with GL remains. I need to consult again with the vendor.